# Matlab clustergram: add color markers by column label

Tags: matlab, bioinformatics, hierarchical-clustering

I'm using [clustergram](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/clustergramobject.html) in the Matlab bioinformatics toolbox. I want to add color markers to certain columns, similarly to [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/examples/working-with-the-clustergram-function.html?refresh=true#zmw57dd0e13882), but I want to mark specific ColumnLabels (IDs) rather than specific clusters.

Anyone know of a way to do that?

Comment: In your first link there is a "Properties for Row and Column Labels" section.  It has `RowLabelsColor` and `ColumnLabelsColor` properties.  Did you try setting those?  You could pass an structure array of the gene IDs

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Based on Kevin's excellent suggestion, I passed a structure with colors for `ColumnLabelsColor`, then set `LabelsWithMarkers` as `true`:

```
clustergram(mat,'Colormap', redbluecmap,'ColumnLabelsColor',s,'LabelsWithMarkers',true)
```

mat is my DataMatrix. s is a structure of 2 cell arrays, each with length of the number of columns: first array is ColumnLabels, second array is my defined colors.

By default, setting `ColumnLabelsColor` changes the color of the text of the labels. Setting `LabelsWithMarkers` to `true` adds a color marker between the label and the clustergram:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestion. I have just figured out this problem.

First step: construct a structure with 'Labels' and 'Colors'. These two cell array should in the same length.

Second step: set the clustergram object, parameter 'ColumnLabelsColor' with this structure.

Also, set 'LabelsWithMarkers' as true.

[This is my original code for your reference ]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTQ1h.png

Comment: ‘ColumnLabels’ should be set as same as 'Lables' in the structure.

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Just copy-paste the code itself, as text, into your answer.